# Combine two equal length vectors alternating

Tags: r

Im struggling with what I feel like there must be a good vectorized way to do it but I am just not finding it. I currently have two equal length vectors and I would like to combine them but I want the first element in vector 1 followed by the first element in vector 2, then second element in vector 1 followed by the second element in vector 2, etc.

```
Vector1 <- c(301L, 50L, 61L, 84L, 90L)
Vector2 <- c(302L, 51L, 62L, 85L, 91L)
```

What I want the result to be (I know I could combine them and use sort but I want to keep the order of them intact (301 & 302 come before the rest).

```
Vector3 <- c(301L, 302L, 50L, 51L, 61L, 62L, 84L, 85L, 90L, 91L)
```

Comment: This may be a duplicate but I find @akrun's answer below to be more concise and elegant than those in the original.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
c(rbind(Vector1, Vector2))
```

Or using `Map`

```
unlist(Map(c, Vector1, Vector2))
```

Comment: Yea that does the trick. Thank you, I will mark this answer when I am able to in 13mins. Quick answer, I cant believe I didnt stumble on it. Thanks for the help.